# web config setting for sub directories and problem in authentication

Tags: asp.net

I create a web site in vs 2015 and create users to log in register sign out so it was ok on the other hand I want to create users for each user
 but got this error

> An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file
>   required to service this request. Please review the specific error
>   details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS
>   //************************
>   1.i create  virtual directory in iis but not respond.
>   2. created web config file in a folder and config it like root config but cant understand how to change it?
>   3.finally i add new web site in this project and  users can register and login ... very well.

so the i do not know adding website for n user is true? or i should create folder for each user and add a config file for that folder? please answer me.thanks...

Comment: Welcome newProgrammer980. Could you please specify your question. It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish and what you want to do.

Comment: Only 1 config file per directory.

Comment: sorry .i have main web site that has root config file. in a folder i add another web config file .i think the problem is parent web config effects on child  one.